# Interfaces exposing properties and Kotlin data classes

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

I've got a data class in Kotlin:

```
data class Image (val name: String, val url: URL) {}
```

I want to serve a list of these Images via REST (Spring Boot, JPA), but I just want certain properties (in this example just the names, not the URLs) to be served. From what I have read I need to use a projection - define an interface with just a 'getName' function:

```
interface HasName {
  fun getName () : String
}
```

..then set the data class to implement this, and get the RestController to serve HasNames rather than Images:

```
@GetMapping("/images")
fun getImages () : List <HasName> {
  return imageService.getImages()
}
```

(or that's what I'd do in Java anyway).

However, if I do this in Kotlin:

```
data class Image (val name: String, val url: URL) : HasName {}
```

I get an error:

> Accidental override: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (getUrl()Ljava/net/URL;):
>
> public final fun `<`get-url`>`(): URL defined in com.figmentsignage.server.data.campaign.Image
> public abstract fun getUrl(): URL defined in com.figmentsignage.server.data.campaign.Image

Is there an easy way around this? I can give the method a different name and redefine it in the Image class, but that's a bit messy. Or I can define the 'name' variable in the interface and override it in the Image, again messy. I ideally want to change the Image class as little as possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how I'd define these in kotlin, just using a `name` property (no need for a `getName()` method) and being sure to use the `override` keyword:

```
interface HasName {
   val name: String
}

data class Image(override val name: String, val url: URL): HasName
```

Comment: I think you are right. I just didn't want to have to make the changes to the Image class. Would this still work if Image implemented 2 interfaces both declaring 'name'?

Comment: should work fine as long as they both declare name w/ the same type